# How to connect mongodb in K8s via a go app

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have a mongodb service up and running. I port-forward to access it locally and in the meantime, I try to check connection with a go app. But I get the error below.

```
panic: error parsing uri: lookup _mongodb._tcp.localhost on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

Port-forward:

```
kubectl port-forward service/mongodb-svc 27017:27017
```

Go app:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    //"log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

func main() {
    username := "username"
    address := "localhost"
    password := "password"
    // Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
    uri := "mongodb+srv://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + address + "/admin?w=majority"
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(uri))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err = client.Disconnect(ctx); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    // Ping the primary
    if err := client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected and pinged.")
}
```

Comment: Your code is trying to look up the IP address of `localhost` on Google's DNS (`8.8.8.8`), for whatever reason. Try using `127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: @Zyl I changed it as you suggested. It didn't work. `panic: error parsing uri: lookup _mongodb._tcp.127.0.0.1 on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host`  And actually I grabbed this code from [mongo db documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup) I cant figure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client is trying to a DNS service lookup because you specified the `+srv` connection type in your URI. Stop doing that and use the correct connection string instead. We do support that in-cluster but not via port forward. I suspect you're trying to mix and match tutorials for both in-cluster and out of cluster. You can't do that.